# Annotating north arrow degree rotation in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, rotate, north-arrow

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

I rotated my data frame for a map, and the north arrow dutifully is rotated as well to show north. I've been told it's possible to annotate the degree rotation on the north arrow symbol itself, but I cannot find the option in map settings or symbol properties.

How can I annotate the degree rotation on a north arrow itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add dynamic text that shows the rotation of the data frame.  Just create a text box with the following dynamic text in it:

```
<dyn type="dataFrame" name="DataFrameName" property="rotation"/>
```

From [ESRI help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000013000000)